# Core Data: Delete the last entity with one to many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nsentitydescription

In my app i have two entity:

[image]

Multiple 'Activities' has records inside.
When i delete the last ActivityRecord entity in the Activities, i want to delete also Activities entity. I did 'nullify' the delete rule of whichDate but Activities not deleted.

Result is here:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete an `Activities` when it has no more `ActivityRecord`s then... you have to delete the `Activities`. There is no way to automate this in Core Data. If you don't want to have any `Activities` objects with no related `ActivityRecord`s, then you need to write your own code that deletes them.

When you're going to delete an `ActivityRecord`, you need to check the related `Activities`. If it doesn't have any more activity records, delete it too.

Comment: +1 for this answer. This can easily be extended by writing a generic method that you use to delete, so that you can use this for other entity/relationships as well.

Comment: Yes, there is no way to automate this in Core Data. Thank you so much.